# Hyperledger Fabric: failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc"

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric

While trying to instantiate a chaincode, I always get a timeout error on lifecycle chaincode (lscc) as follows:

```
2018-04-06 12:36:50.210 UTC [chaincode] Launch -> ERRO 031 launchAndWaitForRegister failed Timeout expired while starting chaincode mycc:1.0(networkid:dev,peerid:org1-peer1,tx:3fa17e226a26f624d4554f7b64572672370838ddb53bc6ae21f0614c61737a51)
2018-04-06 12:36:50.211 UTC [endorser] simulateProposal -> ERRO 032 failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc"  on transaction 3fa17e226a26f624d4554f7b64572672370838ddb53bc6ae21f0614c61737a51, error: Timeout expired while starting chaincode mycc:1.0(networkid:dev,peerid:org1-peer1,tx:3fa17e226a26f624d4554f7b64572672370838ddb53bc6ae21f0614c61737a51)
```

And chaincode container is never created.

EDIT: Timeout issue is solved when I changed the timeout parameters as follows:

**Previously** (not working):

`CORE_CHAINCODE_DEPLOYTIMEOUT=600000
 CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT=600000`

**Correct** (working):

`CORE_CHAINCODE_DEPLOYTIMEOUT=300s
 CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT=300s`

Comment: Chaincode should start in mere seconds, please share the version of your docker images and the context in which you are running (e.g. are you running a sample app or have you written your own).

Comment: can you check whenever chaincode container being created and see logs output? otherwise, try to run peer in debug mode and check output of command which builds chaincode container. alternatively check whenever your chaincode compiles.